# Access window.showmodaldialog via c# WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, showmodaldialog

**Background**

I have a really old website (IE 5 kind of old) in our organization that we have to do some tiresome work on it every morning (around 100 mouse clicks, and you have to start over if you make a mistake). The users copy some existing excel manually to the website). We can't change the system (not even one bit. We don't have access to it).

**Attemps**

I'm trying to automate this process. My idea so far is using c# WebBrowser component and somehow getting things better from there. I've tried capturing the the requsts and resending them but it's using SOAP requests and frankly i think it's not going to be simple.

My current attempt involves injecting javascript to the running code and simulating mouse clicks in the right places. This works fine so far, but I'm stuck because the website is using window.showmodaldialog().

Any ideas how to access the code (both html and javascript)  that's running inside the  dialog?